# How to convert Geodatabase to open standards to process it further?

Tags: polygon, open-source-gis, file-geodatabase, overlay

I have a ESRI file in geodatabase format (v9.3). I intend to use this in a non-commercial application. I think I will have to convert it into a open standard since I am confused if ArcGIS online would need a paid subscription even for a non-commercial 'production' application. (Please let me know if i am wrong about their developer license)

So I am here basically looking for a solution to convert the gdb file/directory to another open format and do below operation: I need to use the gdb data (available data is polygon map overlays) to derive connecting lines from mid point of one polygon to the other polygon. (there would be a huge number of sets of two polygons like this). The end dataset would be a single table having below columns

```
set_id, line_start_point_lat, line_start_point_lon, line_end_point_lat, line_end_point_lon
```

Could anyone tell me what open source technologies I should be looking at to convert and do above operations?

Comment: I think your file geodatabase being pre-10.0 will make things difficult for you - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/reading-filegdb-9-2-9-3-1-with-ogr - otherwise doing something like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83016/how-to-import-esri-geodatabase-format-gdb-into-PostGIS might provide a way forward

Comment: Can I use the ArcGIS 60 day trial or developer subscription to generate the target table format?

Comment: That's a question for Esri if it is not covered in the [Esri Signed License Agreement](http://www.esri.com/legal/software-license).

Answer (score 1):

You can open Esri file geodatabase in QGIS. I am not real familiar with how to run the analysis in QGIS, but I am pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: That depends on the FGDB driver, since Esri's FGDB API will not read 9.x FGDB.

Comment: A reverse engineered GDAL OpenFileGDB driver can read also 9.x FGDB http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html.